# Closing table collapse rows

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have used the bellow HTML code using collapse function which I use from jquery.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead style="background-color: #404e67">
        <tr style="color: white; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">
            <td>Column</td>
            <td>Column</td>
            <td>Column</td>
            <td>Column</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of- 
            rows-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-1">
            <td>SO#</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="group-of-rows-1" class="collapse">
        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of-rows-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-2">
            <td style="padding-left: 30px;">DO#</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="group-of-rows-2" class="collapse">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px;">Event 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px;">Event 2</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I problem is when I click the SO# which is the parent row I want to close the DO# row as well as Event 1, Event 2 rows. but right now when I click on the SO# row it only closes the DO# row, not the Event 1 and Event 2.

I try to use

```
$("#group-of-rows-2 .collapse").collapse('hide');
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues:

- You are use more than 1 time tbody. It should only be used 1 time
- `$("#group-of-rows-2 .collapse").collapse('hide');` is not correct. You say here element with class collapse in element with id group-of-rows-2 and that doesn't exist.
- It's better to use toggle. Example:

  $(".clickable").click(function(){
     $(".group-of-rows-1").toggle();
   });

Comment: No problem, so try to use this $(".trigger").click(function(){ $(".target").toggle(); });

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, i added a Click Me to show you the function, then you can use this sample code to modify like you want. The toggle function hide and show dynamically and you can add some options to the toggle to add effects 
Source of toggle https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```js
$('#group-of-rows-2').click(function(){
      $("#hideMe1").toggle();
      $("#hideMe2").toggle();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
     <thead style="background-color: #404e67">
    <tr style="color: white; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;"> 
     <td>Column</td><td>Column</td><td>Column</td><td>Column</td></tr>
     </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of- 
      rows-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-1">
        <td>SO#</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>  
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
        <tbody id="group-of-rows-1" class="collapse">
              <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of-rows-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-2">
                <td style="padding-left: 30px;">DO#</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>  
                <td>data</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody  class="collapse">
            <tr><td id="group-of-rows-2">Click me</td></tr>
              <tr id="hideMe1">
                  <td style="padding-left: 50px;">Event 1</td>
                  <td>data 1</td>
                  <td>data 1</td>  
                  <td>data 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="hideMe2">
                  <td style="padding-left: 50px;">Event 2</td>
                  <td>data 1</td>
                  <td>data 1</td>  
                  <td>data 1</td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
```